# Jenkins Display version number in the build history coloumn

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that builds and tests a software, What I want to do is, after I build the solution I want to display the version on the build history column. I have seen this done but I dont know how.

Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) if the version number is somewhere in your build log.